# Story with planet sized eye heading to Earth (part of Cthulhu mythos?)

Tags: story-identification

Can someone tell me the name and author of the short story with a planet (or asteroid or meteor) heading towards Earth which, while being observed by one the characters, revolves and reveals itself to actually be a giant eye.

I thought it was one of H. P. Lovecraft's and part of Cthulhu mythos but I've been through all the synopses on [H. P. Lovecraft bibliography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H._P._Lovecraft_bibliography) and couldn't find or recognise it.

**Edit**

We seem to be heading away from Lovecraft, so now I'm thinking it could possibly be a Ramsey Campbell story.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not something written by Lovecraft himself (it doesn't seem like his style). But many anthologies that have "LOVECRAFT" in big letters on the cover have stories by other authors as well.

Comment: I woul have thought *The Fifth Element* until you pointed out that the object in question was actually an eye.

Comment: @Webbie4 I'm almost sure that I read the same story, too. Do you recall that in your story the eye was in fact some kind of living being and it headed to Earth because our planet was an egg which eye endured long time ago?

Comment: @Jenayah Maybe not a good idea to edit the author/work tags into this one, since in the end it *wasn't* a Lovecraft story. The other parts of the edit also seem at best "no improvement whatsoever".

Comment: If anyone wants to give input on the above comment, we're currently discussing it [in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/54248857#54248857)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found it!  It's called '**The Tugging**' (1976) by Ramsey Campbell.  It can be found in the anthology '**Cold Print**' but was first published in '**The Disciples of Cthulhu**', so I was correct in that it is part of the Cthulhu mythos, but wrong about the author. I was also wrong when I mentioned it revolved to reveal itself.

First a bit of background from [this review](https://tentoinfinity.com/2013/07/17/the-tugging-by-ramsey-campbell/):

> Ingels is sleep-deprived, a local newspaper journalist churning out dull articles each day about provincial events that don’t matter. In the background there’s the news that a mysterious wandering planet is passing through the solar system, but it doesn’t affect day-to-day life, so Ingels barely gives it any notice.

This is what really happened:

> Photographs of the planet from the space-probe: one showing an area like a great round pale glistening sea, the next circuit only recording mountains and rock plains. 'Don't you see?' Ingels shouted at Bert among the packed faces. 'It closed its eye when it saw us coming!'